# knockout binding after array updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have an array that I'm removing items from but I'm keeping count of the number of items to do UI formatting. I need to be able to have the bind update.

```
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    getFoos();


var viewModel = {
    foos: ko.observableArray([]),

    reloadFoos: function () {
        getFoos();
    },

    removeFoo: function () {
        remove(this);
    }
};

var foo = function () {
    this.Id = ko.observable();
    this.Name = ko.observable();
    this.Count = ko.observable();
};

function remove(foo) {
    viewModel.foos.splice(viewModel.foos.indexOf(foo), 1);

    viewModel.foos.each(function(index) {
        viewModel.foos[index].Count = index%10 == 0;
    });
}

function getFoos() {
    viewModel.foos([]);
    $.get("/myroute/", "", function (data) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var f = new foo();
            f.Id = data[i];
            f.Name = data[i];
            f.Count = i%10 == 0;
            viewModel.foos.push(f);
        }

    });
}

            <div data-bind="foreach: foos">
                <div style="float: left">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-bind="click : $parent.removeFoo, attr: { id: Id }">
                            <label data-bind="value: Name"></label>
                        </a>
                </div>
                <!-- ko if: Count -->
                <div style="clear: left"></div>
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
```

When the click event fires the item is removed from the array but the if bind doesn't get updated and the ui formatting is off. I'm trying to keep from reloading the data because the ui block bounces as it removes and reloads.

Comment: You're going to have a performance problem with your code as well. Within getFoos you're clearing the observable array, then within the loop you're pushing items 1 by 1 to the observable array. If you have 100 items in data, you'll fire the update on the observable array 101 times. You should build the array just like a normal javascript array and then set the observable array = to that array you built at the end. The update on the observable array is fired only once.

Comment: I'm not anticipating many items, but thanks for the info.

Comment: It's still worth fixing, since it's a 2-line fix. Especially if you have many subscribers to that observable array. I've seen IE8 and 9 choke on that.

Comment: Can you provide your view/HTML?

Comment: The whole thing? The elements are at the bottom in the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your UI is not being updated because when you do your assignment to `Count`, you aren't assigning as an observable. You are replacing the observable with a straight boolean value.  So, your assignment calls like this one:

```
viewModel.foos[index].Count = index%10 == 0;
```

Will cause `viewModel.foos[index].Count` to be equal to `true` or `false` and the value won't be stored in the observable.

That line should be this instead:

```
viewModel.foos[index].Count(index%10 == 0);
```

That will set the observable correctly. Note that you must change all of your assignments to observables to be set this way. See the "Reading and Writing Observables" section of this page: [Knockout Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html).

Comment: Made the change to set Count as Count(index%10==0), as well as the other observables and it didn't change the ui issue.